# Show/Hide Text JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that has the function show/hide for text, right now "Show Text" and "Hide Text" are both visible, anyone have any ideas how I can have the links showing and hiding too?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".content_post").hide();

  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".content_post").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by have the links showing and hiding? perhaps add some HTML to your question to explain what you are trying to do in more detail

Comment: Can you share your html too please...

Comment: You've demonstrated that you already know how to use `$.show` & `$.hide`, just call those same functions on the `a` tags.

Comment: Here is the HTML <a href = "javascript:" id="hide">Hide Text</a>
   <a href = "javascript:" id="show">Show Text</a>
<div class = "content_post">
</div><!--end post content-->

Answer (score 1):

This also should works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
       $(".content_post").hide();
       $(this).hide();
       $("#show").show();

    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".content_post").show();
        $(this).hide();
        $("#hide").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".content_post").hide();
    $("#hide").hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });

  $("#show").click(function(){
    $(".content_post").show();
    $("#hide").show();
    $("#show").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 2 buttons, why don't you only use one, with the `.toggle()`, that way you don't have to hide and show buttons.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.content_post').toggle();
});
```

Here is a [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to the to the docs if you want to check it out. Also if you want to give a more fancy effect you could try the `.slideToggle()` or the `.fadeToggle()`, I personally like more the fade.